# Create a Chrome cube in OpenGL / Glut?

Tags: opengl, glut, cube

I'm attempting to make a chromed cube in GLUT / OpenGL and I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

I looked up a "Materials Table" in a textbook which showed "Chrome" as being:
Ambient: (0.25, 0.25, 0.25), Diffuse: (0.4, 0.4, 0.4), and Specular: (0.774597,0.774597,0.774597).

My question is, how do I create a simple cube and apply this material/texture to it in Glut/OpenGL?

Do I use "glutSolidCube()"?  If so, how do I then apply the chrome texture to it?

Can any GLUT/OpenGL people point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be as simple as calling [`glMaterialfv()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMaterial.xml) before [`glutSolidCube()`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__geometry.html#ga1).

I haven't done OpenGL since school, but here's some display loop code from an old project that used a sphere that should get you on the right track:

```
_Ambient[CHROME][0] = 0.25f;
_Ambient[CHROME][1] = 0.25f;
_Ambient[CHROME][2] = 0.25f;
_Ambient[CHROME][3] = 1.0f;
_Diffuse[CHROME][0] = 0.4f;
_Diffuse[CHROME][1] = 0.4f;
_Diffuse[CHROME][2] = 0.4f;
_Diffuse[CHROME][3] = 1.0f;
_Specular[CHROME][0] = 0.774597f;
_Specular[CHROME][1] = 0.774597f;
_Specular[CHROME][2] = 0.774597f;
_Specular[CHROME][3] = 1.0f;
_Shininess[CHROME] = 76.8f;


void Display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  glPushMatrix();
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, _Ambient[CHROME]);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, _Diffuse[CHROME]);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, _Specular[CHROME]);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, _Shininess[CHROME]);
    // Translations...
    glutSolidSphere(_Radius, _Slices, _Stacks);
  glPopMatrix();

  glFlush();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me to re-open that project, I wrote some neat code (well, in my opinion) that I had forgotten about!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at environment mapping? You want your object to reflect light from other objects in the environment, so you basically apply a texture that looks like the environment and generate texture coordinates based on normals. This will give the surface a mirrored appearance. You can have OpenGL automatically generate texture coordinates for each vertex based with [`glTexGen`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/texgen.html).

[NeHe tutorial 23](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=23) covers this with sphere mapping. You can also generate your own texture coordinates per-vertex or per-pixel using GLSL. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_texturing.php) on that.